# Error: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [49400, 1]

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Here is my code

```
from pandas import read_csv
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.svm import SVC
import pandas as pd

#Load dataset
df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\dhava\OneDrive\Documents\Folder to run environment for Anaconda\Poseidon\Pump_Dataset.csv")
print(df.columns)
```

output  file contains the fllowing columns

```
Index(['id', 'target_status', 'amount_tsh', 'date_recorded', 'funder',
       'gps_height', 'installer', 'longitude', 'latitude', 'wpt_name',
       'num_private', 'basin', 'subvillage', 'region', 'region_code',
       'district_code', 'lga', 'ward', 'population', 'public_meeting',
       'recorded_by', 'scheme_management', 'scheme_name', 'permit',
       'construction_year', 'extraction_type', 'extraction_type_group',
       'extraction_type_class', 'management', 'management_group', 'payment',
       'payment_type', 'water_quality', 'quality_group', 'quantity',
       'quantity_group', 'source', 'source_type', 'source_class',
       'waterpoint_type', 'waterpoint_type_group'],
      dtype='object')
```

When I try to run the following code I encounter the above mentioned error

```
inputs= df[['id', 'amount_tsh', 'date_recorded', 'funder',
       'gps_height', 'installer', 'longitude', 'latitude', 'wpt_name',
       'num_private', 'basin', 'subvillage', 'region', 'region_code',
       'district_code', 'lga', 'ward', 'population', 'public_meeting',
       'recorded_by', 'scheme_management', 'scheme_name', 'permit',
       'construction_year', 'extraction_type', 'extraction_type_group',
       'extraction_type_class', 'management', 'management_group', 'payment',
       'payment_type', 'water_quality', 'quality_group', 'quantity',
       'quantity_group', 'source', 'source_type', 'source_class',
       'waterpoint_type', 'waterpoint_type_group']]

outputs = [['target_status']]

X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(inputs, outputs, test_size=0.20, random_state=1)
```

I see that both inputs and outputs have same dimensions

Comment: For the next time, please do spend a minute to see how to properly format your code snippets (done it for you this time)

Comment: This is just a typo, you missed the `df` in this line: `outputs = df[['target_status']]`.